# Send mail using Amazon web SES from Android application

Tags: java, android, email, amazon-ses

I am developing an app in which I want to send mail from app without user intervention (without using intents), and it is not good to take the user credentials (without using Java mail API), but how to bind the body of the mail from Android application to Web API? Here is my code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if (v == btnSend) {
 String url = "http://app.xyz.com/api/SendMail/SendMail?Emailid=xyz@gmail.com" + "&Subject=" + "&Body=";
       if (url != null) {
            email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
            subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString();
            message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[]{"xyz@gmail.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));

           }
           }catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
           "Request failed try again: " + t.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
```

Comment: you can send using SMTP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: While posting this question i have searched in stack overflow.But i don't get the proper method.First understand my post.while using Java Mail API,it will ask user to enter name and password.And i don't want to user password in my app because of security.

Comment: Miss that user name and password is for SMTP  so you can add it statically

Comment: Please explain me how to implement

Comment: And if you dnt want to give password username of Server then there is no other way i think to send mail. because without credential you cant use any services.

Comment: I am using Amazon web services for sending mail then what is the need of using SMTP. I wrote the service in .net .The mail was going perfectly.But the problem which i am facing is how to bind body of the mail from android application to the service which i have written

Comment: Dear you have edited question so its not my fault. I was given suggestion on base of your before questions.

Comment: Apologize  for my  mistake.Please help me how to do it.

Comment: see this i think its help you.https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3290993028247679

Comment: I saw.but how to proceed i didn't get

Comment: Please help me how to send the a mail from android application using amazon web services

Comment: have you check that link which i was suggest you

Comment: so whats problem you get?

Comment: More then 40 java files they have given.While integrating them so many exceptions are there.Even i didn't know the procedure i am following is right or wrong.If u knoow how to send the mail from android application using amazon web services please help me

Comment: I Downloaded AWS sdk-ses for android  and tried to integrate them.

Comment: i am also not working with amazon SES dear . check this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/

Comment: I checked.They are using apache open source license.But in my project i am not using apache.I am using android studio.

Comment: add this in gradle below buildtoolVersion   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Comment: I am Struggling from so many days.At last mail was going.Thank You For helping me @Vishal Thakkar.I will edit my code now.

Comment: What you doing wrong??

Comment: I wrote the credentials in controller using web API.But i did not write the credentials information in webconfig

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution.In order send mail using **Amazon SES**.

We should have Amazon credentials.Use that Credentials and write a controller in .net using web API and call the URL in our android application.

Below is my android code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feed_back);
    scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myAwesomeTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextview);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Subject = mEdit.getText().toString();
    mEdit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    Body = mEdit1.getText().toString();
    Log.d("###$Request URL", Subject + "");
    Log.d("###$Request URL", Body + "");
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(main.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String  e = sharedpreferences.getString(main.email,"");
    String url ="http://app.xyz.com/Api/SendMail/SendMail?Emailid="+ e + "&Subject="+ Subject+"&Body=" +Body;
    AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(FeedBack.this);
    mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>()
    {
    @Override
    public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status)
    {
    super.callback(url, data, status);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    {
        Log.d("###$Request URL", url + "");
        Log.d("###$Response ", data + "");
        Log.d("###$Status Message : ", status.getMessage() + "");
        Log.d("###$Status Code : ", status.getCode() + "");

    }
    if(status.getCode()!=-101)
    {
       String StringData = "" + data;
       try 
       {
         JSONObject json = new JSONObject(StringData);
         String sd,hd;
         sd = json.getString("Subject");
         hd=  json.getString("Body");

       } 
       catch (Exception a) 
       {
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(FeedBack.this,"Mail Sending", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          toast.show();
       }
       }
       else
       {
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(FeedBack.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
         toast.show();

       }
        }
        });
        }
     });
   }
}
```